# Setting up a server in python and getting a thread exception, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, exception, runtime-error

I am programming a server in python and have multiple threads doing different tasks at the same time. I've been trying to handle the threads whenever there is a keyboard interruption.

Here is the code for the central thread:

```
import shutdownManager as SM
import initManager as IM
import nodeListManager as NLM
import threading

print("<Server Started>")

SM.bootup()

INITTRACKER_THREAD = threading.Thread(target = IM.nodeInitTracker)
NODELISTCLEANER_THREAD = threading.Thread(target = NLM.nodeListCleaner, args = ("NodeList.txt",))
try:
    NODELISTCLEANER_THREAD.start()
    INITTRACKER_THREAD.start()

    NODELISTCLEANER_THREAD.join()
    INITTRACKER_THREAD.join()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n<Shutting Server Down>")
    SM.shutdown()
```

I'm sending shutdown signals via a file, and it is being checked constantly by the thread. The `NODELISTCLEANER_THREAD` works and exits just how I want it to.
The problem is with the other thread.

Here is the code for the other thread:

```
import shutdownManager as SM
import socket

def nodeInitTracker():
    #Create Socket
    s = socket.socket()

    #HTTP Port, this forces is you to run with admin/root
    port = 80

    #Bind and listen for node and client connections
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)
    print('<Socket Bounded>: Now Listening')

    #Client and Node Management
    while True:

        #Accept connection
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print('<CONNECTION ESTABLISHED>: With ', addr[0])
        c.send(('1').encode())

        if SM.checkShutdown():
            print('<Initialization Manager Turned Off>')
            c.close()
            s.close()
            break

        #Perform the process that belongs to their respective device type
        DeviceType = c.recv(1024).decode()
        if DeviceType == 'n':
            #Recieve Node Name
            NodeName = c.recv(1024).decode()
            print('<Node Name Confirmed>: ', NodeName, ' Belongs to ', addr[0])

            #Store Node Name in Node List
            fNodeList = open('NodeList.txt', 'a')
            fNodeList.write(addr[0] + "        " + NodeName + "\n")
            print("<Recorded Node into Node List>: " + NodeName)
            fNodeList.close()
        else:
            #Receive info from the client
            #Please note, that this will be done later. So don't worry about it right now
            print('<Client Connections are not implemented yet>')

        #Close connection with client or node
        c.close()
```

This is the error:

> CException ignored in: 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
>           t.join()
>        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1054, in join
>           self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1070, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>           elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
>       KeyboardInterrupt

Is there a way to fix this?